# Is my honey fermented?

Tags: food-safety

I have a gallon of honey, stored in an ice cream bucket, that smells like sour krout and has little air bubbles all the way thru it. Should i consider it unsafe to use? will baking with it make it safer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/91505/is-my-honey-fermenting

Answer (score 5):

Promoted to answer as requested:

Bubbles suggest fermentation is going on. A vinegary smell suggest it's aerobic fermentation. I'd guess you're heading towards vinegar, not mead. Simmering will reduce water content, which will inhibit bacterial and fungal growth. A gallon weighing 10-12 pounds, At $8 to $10 per Lb, 10Lbs is well worth trying to rescue. I'd simmer off about 10-15% of your volume. Should be enough to reduce water activity below where things will grow, and get rid of any vinegar. Watch the stuff. It may still be a bit too watery. I've made a rough guess here.

Comment: I have read on several different occasions that pure honey is the only food on this planet that will never go bad.  Why would this honey start to ferment?

Comment: @Hutchette High water content. Perhaps caused by an overly wet season, or someone diluting the honey a little, so as to make a larger profit upon selling. Long lasting honey will have a water activity around 0.5. Let it get up to 0.62, and you can start having yeast problems:https://www.metergroup.com/food/articles/microbial-growth/